# How to change the Iframe map size to full screen in Shopify Atlantic theme

Tags: google-maps, shopify, customization, shopify-template

I'm using Atlantic theme and I create a new page for Map. 
I used the following code which is mention below

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d27728.56583382997!2d-95.647502!3d29.688729!3m2!..." width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="">
```

Please help me to get it to the full size, I have used the creating new layout method but still it does not work.
It only worked when I wrote the layout null {% layout none %}
But I wan it with the theme 
I don't want to make the layout null.
The screenshot is attached below
[image: ify]

Answer (score 1):

Set the height and width of the `<iframe>` to 100% with CSS:

```
html, body, iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wbroyLps/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3466.07056567071!2d-95.64969038455021!3d29.688733742242416!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8640df708f47547b%3A0x21b117877ecdc1e7!2sMW%20Furniture%20Outlet!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1571677313661!5m2!1sen!2sus"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you defined sizes for all containing elements?